# IE6 Losing Querystring

Tags: javascript, query-string

I have a page that grabs values from the query string using javascript `window.location`. This works fine when run from a webserver but if I run it locally using IE6 by putting this in the address bar

```
c:\mysite\index.htm
```

Any query strings the site creates get lost and `window.location` just contains the location upto `.htm`.

I realize the example above has no query string but that page links off to pages that do. This also fails when running from a network share e.g `\\server\mysite\index.htm`. It seems to work fine in IE7+ and only fails in IE6.

Any ideas it's driving me crazy.

Edit : I've jsut realised this is happening on a modal window does that make any difference?

Comment: http://iedeathmarch.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that IE6 disregards any querystrings when running locally on modal windows. Got around the problem by passing the variables into the modal window as dialog arguments rather than querystrings.

Answer (score 4):

Query strings explicitly do not exist for URIs of the scheme ‘file’. See [RFC1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738#section-3.10). It makes no sense to put a ?query on the end of a ‘file:’ URI.

If you want to include extra location information available to scripts on the page, use a #fragment identifier and location.hash.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a security issue in IE6. The only thing I can think of is using a HTA instead of a HTML file. Is that an option?

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that `window.location` is not a simple string, but a [structured object](http://www.w3schools.com/HTMLDOM/dom_obj_location.asp) with fields? The querystring is in `window.location.search` - apparently IE6 simply does not include that part when printing the parent object.

Comment: yes I'm aware of this, IE6 seems to loose the search text when run offline

Comment: hm, that's a nasty quirk then.

Comment: it also seems to prepend the location with file:// not sure if this makes any difference in the way it runs

Comment: It prepends the location with file:// because you are using the file protocol rather than the HTTP protocol. As bobince points out, a querystring has no meaning in relation to the file protocol. It's an HTTP thing, so IE is perfectly within its rights to throw it away for file system access. If you want to use HTTP, you need to run an HTTP server.