# How do i click on a link that loads a html page and then using ajax (without clicking anything) load an external html page?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, loading

html with a link to page2.html and when page2.html is loading i want to load inside it with AJAX the content of page3.html. Can someone provide me with a solution? i have tried this but it doesnt work.

```
//link icon to correspoding link on what we do
$('#websites').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('href', function() {
        $('#loading_content').load('what-we-do.html/istoselides').fadeIn(1000);
    })
});
```

Thanks so much!

**UPDATE**

```
<li id="adv"><a href="what_we_do.html?istoselides">adv</a></li>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
     if (window.location.search == "?istoselides") {
          #('#loading_content').load('what-we-do.html/istoselides').fadeIn(1000);
     }
});
```

Comment: please add the links code.. #website, is a div? an a? give more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass information from page1 to page2 through the href, but not code, so you'll have to set a keyword of some sort, for example in the *query string*, and let page2 extract this information:

**page1.html**

```
<a href="page2.html?loadPage3">Link to Page2</a>
```

**page2.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
         if (window.location.search == "?loadPage3") {
              $('#loading_content').load('what-we-do.html/istoselides').fadeIn(1000);
         }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i think he meant to load page3 into page2 only when that certain link from page1 is pressed.. correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: @Noam, ah that seems to make more sense. I'll wait for a response from the OP then.

Comment: Thanks ill take a look at it now and post what i come up with. Thanks Box and Noam! :)

Comment: no luck Box. I go to the page2 but page3 doesnt load automatically after that.

Comment: `#('#loading_content')` typo of [Box9](http://stackoverflow.com/users/405143/box9).. should have been `$('#loading_content')`. changed `#` to `$`.

Comment: Thanks Reigel. @NASH, there was a typo on my side. See Reigel's comment above, or the updated code (changed `#('#loading_content')` to `$('#loading_content')`).

Comment: Box i have changed it and it still doesnt work. Maybe im doing sth else wrong. on the url i dont see any change. shouldnt it be: file:///C:/Users/sth/Desktop/sth%20Web%20-%20Copy/what_we_do.html?istoselides and instead i get file:///C:/Users/sth/Desktop/sth%20Web%20-%20Copy/what_we_do.html

Comment: @NASH, ah that's why. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304101/ie6-losing-querystring/1304986#1304986. Do you intend to put it on the web eventually? If you're using `http://` then you'll be fine.

Comment: yes i do :D I hope it works!! Thanks for your help :D. I have one more question if u dont mind that i would like to ask you. Is that ok?

Comment: Ok good luck. You can ask me if it's quick and relates to this question, but you're probably better off asking a new question on the site. You'll get more answers that way and I'll be away for a bit...